# CSS grid display in one row 4 columns or 2 rows 2 colums

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to display 4 elements with grid and in a responsive way. What I want to achieve is to have the 4 element or in one row and 4 columns or 2 rows and 2 columns. My solution don't work in all screen width but I don't know how to fix the problem (in some screen width it go in 2 rows 3 columns so the first rows have 3 elements and the second only 1 as show [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpc5S.jpg))

I would appreciate any suggestion that use the grid system!

Thank you in advance

```css
.top-news-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(15rem, 50%), 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(5rem, auto);
  gap: 1.6rem;
  padding-bottom: 3.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-news-container">
   <article class="top-news">First article in a card style</article>
   <article class="top-news">Second article in a card style</article>
   <article class="top-news">Third article in a card style</article>
   <article class="top-news">Fourth article in a card style</article>
</div>
```

Comment: use media query or wrap each two article inside a div

Comment: Thank you I will use one of your solution even if I was curious if I could achieve what I asked modify only the grid-template-columns...thank you anyways 